# All possible solutions of an equations in R

Tags: r, equation-solving

I want to write an R code to generate all  distinct solution of the equation x1+x2+...+xm=n, where n is a positive integer and xi>=0, is a non-negative interger.

I have written an R code for this purpose, but I don't like its run time. Furthermore, it dose not work for relatively large values of m and n, like n=m=10.
My code is as follows.

```
 A<-matrix(ncol=m,nrow=choose((n+m-1),(m-1)))
  a<-1
  for (h in 1:((n+1)^m)) {
        l <- rep(NA, m)
        for (il in 1:m) {
            l[il] <- (((h-1) %/% ((n+1)^(il-1))) %% (n+1)) + 1
            l[il]<-l[il]-1
        }
         if(sum(l)==n) { A[a,]<-l;a<-a+1}
    }
  A
```

Dose anybody know a more efficient way for finding the solutions of that equation?
Thank you.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632322/finding-all-possible-combinations-of-numbers-to-reach-a-given-sum though you'd need to adapt it to R.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are going through many more combinations of numbers than needed. As you put in your code, n + m - 1 choose m - 1 represents the number of solutions that will satisfy this sort of problem. Think about why this works as follows: we want to split up n into m groups. If we lined up our n elements side by side, we need to make m-1 chops to create m groups. We can think about each chop as it's own element. Let's use n=8, m=5 to think about it concretely. It's as if we need to divide up 8 a's into 5 groups (4 chops, represented by "/"). This is the same as if we had a row of 12 empty spaces, and we had to put 8 a's and 4 /'s in the row. A sample output could be:

a a / / a / a a a a / a

If we find the difference between the indices of the slashes and subtract one (and pretend there are 2 extra slashes on the outside indices of 0 and n+m), we can find each solution. For the example above, the 5 numbers would be 2 (3 - 0 - 1), 0 (4 - 3 - 1), 1 (6 - 4 - 1), 4 (11 - 6 - 1), and 1 (13 - 11 - 1). Therefore, if we generate all of the (n + m - 1) choose (m - 1) results, we can do simple subtraction, and don't need to worry about any extra combinations.

We can emulate this with the code too, using the `combinations()` function in the `gtools` library.

```
library(gtools)
nums <- rep(0, m)
combs <- combinations(n + m - 1, m - 1)
for(i in 1:choose(n + m - 1,m - 1)){
  for(j in 1:m){
    #edge case for beginning
    if(j == 1){
      nums[j] <- combs[i, j] - 1
    }
    #edge case for end
    else if(j == m){
      nums[j] <- n + m - combs[i, j-1] - 1
    }
    else {
      nums[j] <- combs[i, j] - combs[i, j-1] - 1
    }
  }
  A[i,] <- nums
}
```

If you want to further speed things up, you can put the inner for loop in a function that takes in a row of the combinations matrix, n, and m, and returns a single row of the solution output you want. Then, you can use an apply function on that function:

```
rowSummer <- function(spaces, size, max){
  nums <- rep(0, size)
  for(j in 1:size){
    if(j == 1){
      nums[j] <- spaces[j] - 1
    }
    else if(j == size){
      nums[j] <- max - spaces[j-1] - 1
    }
    else {
      nums[j] <- spaces[j] - spaces[j-1] - 1
    }
  }
  nums
}

combs <- combinations(n+m-1, m-1)
A <- apply(combs, 1, rowSummer, size=m, max=n+m)
t(A)
```

However, the original solution above already speeds things up a great deal by only going through the necessary combinations.